# Create new Excel workbook blind from a single sheet in an open workbook

Tags: excel, file, save, export, creation

I'm trying to create a new Excel file from an open sheet. I've been through several solutions here but none of them quite get to what I need. I'm not very good with Excel file interaction out on disk. This is Excel 2010.

1. I have some VBA code that writes out relevant data to a new sheet (let's say Sheet3).
2. Then, I would like to write out all of Sheet3 to a new Excel file "output.xlsx" in a given folder (let's say F:\test)
3. I was hoping the process would create the xlsx file blind, populate Sheet1, save, and close the file without the user ever seeing the open output.xlsx file.

EDIT #2: working with this exact code:

```
Dim FPath As String, FName As String, filenamex As String
Dim NewBook As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FPath = "F:\test\"
FName = "output" & ".xlsx"
filenamex = FPath & FName
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:N100").Copy 
Destination:=NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
NewBook.Close savechanges:=True, Filename:=filenamex

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Result #2:
(a) The excel file output.xls is created and SAVED (thank you)
(b) Three sheets are created as exists in the original file
(c) All three sheets are still blank. I only need Sheet3 copied from the original file.

Thanks

Comment: *But it's not working out...* That is pretty vague. What is not working? What is it doing/not doing that you expect? If you create a [mcve] for us that will help us help you more clearly. One thing I see is that removing `PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)` from the `.Copy` procedure will make that line work copy the data to the destination as needed

Comment: Thanks Scott. Edited original

Comment: Edit #2 - thank for the save and close @BruceWayne

Comment: (Please don't edit your questions with the solutions.  Instead, you can mark the working code as the Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.  Editing your original post effectively erases the question, and makes it hard for future users to see what your issue was, and how it was solved.)

Comment: Got It BruceWayne - thank you. But we're not solved yet. The resulting sheet is still blank. Please see Edit #2

Comment: @JohnJoseph - see my comment under Bruce's answer. Also, the reason you have 3 sheets appear in `NewBook` is because in the Excel Options the default is to open a workbook with 3 new sheets. You can change to 1 if you like, or write code to remove the 2 extra sheets.

Comment: Yeah, I missed a reference. Check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primarily, you can just turn off `ScreenUpdating`.

```
Sub copy_to_new()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim FPath As String, FName As String, filenamex As String
Dim NewBook As Workbook, oldBook as Workbook

Set oldBook = ActiveWorkbook 
'Or use `ThisWorkbook` if you're running this code from the workbook you want to copy from.

FPath = "F:\test\"
FName = "output.xls"
filenamex = FPath & FName
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
oldBook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:N100").Copy Destination:=NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Application.CutCopyMode = False

' We can use the .Close command to close and save the file in one line
NewBook.Close savechanges:=True, Filename:=filenamex

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to qualify the workbook in this line `Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:N100").Copy`. As written it will copy Sheet3 from `NewBook` since it's the active book at the spot in the execution.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Ah! Don't know how I missed that, thanks for catching it.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - See my edit of my edit...I'm not sure if OP is running the code from the workbook to copy from, so defaulted to `ActiveWorkbook`.